# Notation question: linear map $P(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, linear-transformations

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{C}^5$ and the map $P:\mathbb{C}^5\mapsto\mathbb{C}^5$, 
$P(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(x_1,x_2,0,0,0)$.
Am I supposed to read $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ as 5 *vectors* or as the 5 entries of a single vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're five entries of a vector; $P$ has domain $\mathbb C^5$ so each $x_i$ is a complex number.